# Finding a basis for which a linear transformation is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$T : P_2 → P_2$ is deﬁned by $T(p(t)) = (t + 1)^2p^{''}(t)−(t + 1)p^{'}(t) + 3p(t)$.
I have gotten that a generic formula in terms of the coefficients is $3at^2 + (2a+2b)t + (2a-b+3c)$. To find the basis of eigenvectors, we first find the matrix of T with respect to the standard basis. 
So, $[T]_S = ([T(1)]_S |[T(t)]_S |[T(t^2)]_S)$.

How does this equal $([3]_S |[2t−1]_S |[3t^2 + 2t + 2]_S)$?

Comment: What is $T(1)$? What is $T(t)$? What is $T(t^2)$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you do not *have* to first work in the standard basis.

The factor $(t+1)$ occurs all over the place. So we rather develop $p$ around $-1$:
$$\begin{align}p(t)&=a_0+ a_1(t+1)+a_2(t+1)^2,\\
p'(t)&=a_1+2a_2(t+1),\\
p''(t)&=2a_2.
\end{align}$$As we multiply the derivatives with corresponding powers of $(t+1)$, it turns out that everything sorts out nicely, i.e., $1$, $1+t$, $(1+t)^2$ are already eigenvectors (with eigenvalues you can readily find).